# 1998 smoke imagery in Alaska

Tags: google-earth-engine, imagery, cloud-cover, earth-explorer

I am trying to access smoke/cloud imagery above the Alaska region during August of 1998. I would like to use GEE, but I haven't been able to find a dataset with good coverage. I have looked at Landsat 5, NOAA_CDR_PATMOSX_V53, and used Earth Explorer to look at a few images from AVHRR (but I can't seem to filter these based on day and location). Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Could you please edit your question to show the GEE code that you have tried and any error messages? When you looked at the available LS 5 imagery, what issue did you encounter?

Comment: you may also want to ask this question in the open data stackexchange page. https://opendata.stackexchange.com/